# Populate email subject line with form entries in Google Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am completely new to Google Scripts. I experimented with the script found [here](https://snipe.net/2013/04/26/email-contents-google-form/) (as written by Snipe and edited by Govoni in the first comment).

What I am trying to do is combine both scripts, to get an email on form submit that would:

- only show answered questions (it works)
- format questions in bold (it works)
- populate the subject line (I can't get it to work)

The code below works.

```js
function newResponse()

{
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var formName = ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
var lastRow = formName.getLastRow();
var lastColumn = formName.getLastColumn();
var email = "sample@myemail.com"; 
var name = "My Email";
var subject = 'New form response: ';
var body = '';
var cell = '';
for (var i = 1; i <= lastColumn ; i++)
{
var title = formName.getRange(1,i).getDisplayValue();
var cell = formName.getRange(lastRow, i).getDisplayValue();
if (cell != '' && cell != 0)
{
body = body + '<b>'+ title + '</b>: ' + cell + '<br>';
};
};

MailApp.sendEmail({
to: email,
name: name,
subject: subject,
htmlBody: body
});
}
```

So, to try and add variable entries to the subject line I changed 'function newResponse()' to 'function newResponse(e)' and added this line before MailApp:sendEmail:

```js
// The email subject line should look like this: "New form response: Item (Company, Country)"
// Item, Company and Country are the 2nd, 3rd and 4th columns from my form
subject += e.namedValues[title[1]].toString() + " (" + e.namedValues[title[2]].toString()+ ", "
+ e.namedValues[title[3]].toString()+ ")";
```

But when I do this, it doesn't send an email at all. If I change e.namedValues and instead put something like [title[0]], it then returns the first letter of the last question answered.

I am not quite sure what to try next?

Answer (score 1):

From your code snippet, I suppose `title` variable holds a string, so `title[0]` is the first character of the string. `e.namedValues[title[1]]` will be `undefined` if no questions are single-character. `undefined.toString()` will throw an error, crashing the entire script.

You'll need to save an array of titles of all columns in the sheet.

```
var titles = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= lastColumn ; i++) {
  var title = formName.getRange(1,i).getDisplayValue();
  titles.push(title);
  var cell = formName.getRange(lastRow, i).getDisplayValue();
  ...
}
```

Afterwards, you'll be able to use `e.namedValues[titles[1]]`. Note that I use `titles`, the array.

Comment: Thank you ever so much: I split my head over this problem and your code works beautifully! Sadly I can't up vote your answer because of my non-existent reputation but I am extremely grateful.

Comment: Glad my solution helps!

Answer (score 0):

Subject is not a member of the advanced parameters object its just a mailapp.senEdmail parameter.

Try:

```
sendEmail(email, subject, '', {name: name, htmlBody: body});
```